# Remove a specific dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog

Inside an app we have various dialogs. In one case for example:

The user clicks a button and gets a "loading dialog".
The client gets a news notification as a "notification dialog".
The user gets the loaded data and and gets forwarded to a page showing the data.

So the "history"/"hierarchie" should be
["loading dialog", "notification dialog", "data page"]

When the data is loaded we want to remove the "loading dialog" which is in the history below the other dialog and below the data page.

How can I tell a specific dialog in flutter to close?

Currently the page showing the data has a named route and the dialogs are opened via showDialog(...)

Comment: dont use showDialog, show the Dialogue in a stack widget, hide it when the condition is met!!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this out

```
final route = DialogRoute(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => const CupertinoAlertDialog(
    content: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
      radius: 25,
    ),
  ),
);

Navigator.of(context).push(route);
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
Navigator.of(context).removeRoute(route);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `Navigator.of(context).pop()` to remove dialogs that come from `showDialog(...)`. So if you call it before you push the new page on it will work. You'll need to ensure you have a build context to use though, but otherwise it will work.

This also works for anything that's pushed onto the Navigator stack, like a modal bottom sheet via `showModalBottomSheet(...)`.

Comment: The problem in the question is that we want to keept the higher level dialog (notification dialog) and the newly pushed page...
There also could be a bunch of other dialogs between the new page and the loading dialog...

Comment: Okay, maybe you should try out Navigator 2.0 (a new alternative to the classic way of handling navigation in Flutter). A good tutorial on it can be found here: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade. It allows for a `List` of Pages which you can then update in any way you'd like.